# Can we not read audio files (like MP3 file encoded in MPEG-1) without using libraries in python?

Tags: python, audio, file-read

I have an audio file named audiofile.mp3 in a folder. 
I am reading it using python in the way described below:-

```
wheat = open('C:\\Users\\username\\folder\\audiofile.mp3',encoding = "MPEG-1",errors = 'ignore')

wheat.read()
```

But it returns output in binary format.

I just want to know whether we can read that audio file (mp3 file encoded in MPEG-1) without using python libraries. I mean I have found a lot on reading audio files by using python libraries on google but I want to do it in the basic way. I am on windows 10 and using python3.

Thankew in advance!

Comment: `MPEG-1` is not an __encoding__, it's a ***file format***. To read an MP3 without using any libraries you'll need to read and understand what the bytes of an mp3 file mean & translate that into python code

Comment: @rdas how can we do that possibly? Btw, I searched entire google but I didn't find what encoding is used in mp3 files. Can you tell me that too?

Comment: An mp3 file is just a binary file. The format describes how the data is laid out in the file & how to interpret it. You can check the [wikipedia article on mp3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Design)

Comment: @rdas I also want to know how we can understand bytes of me file and translate that into python code that you mentioned. I want a brief overview of that. Also, can you suggest some resources to understand encoding, bit, bytes, binary and that low level stuff because google gives just overview of that not like some examples in depth? Thanks!

Comment: These are thing you should be learning in college / from textbooks. Not stackoverflow.